# Why can't I drill into studs more than 1 & 1/2 inches?

Tags: drill, studs

I am trying to mount a TV onto an "exterior" wall. I used the quotes because I guess technically it may not be exterior (I live in a townhouse with dividing walls between the houses).

Anyway, I've done this before at a different location with no problems. However, I am drilling guide holes and cannot seem to drill into the wall more than 1.5" (not sure the width of the sheetrock in that). I've tried drilling into multiple studs at multiple heights and get the same issue.

I do not want to saw the drywall just to look at the stud. Does anyone have any guesses as to what might be going on?

**Additional info:**

- House was built in the 70s
- Tip of drill bit is much hotter than I'd expect.
- Didn't have this issue with the stud in-between the two studs in question.

Comment: Are you allowed to drill into party walls? That said, my guess is you may have masonry firewalls between each unit.

Comment: This is not a condo. I am drilling into a stud that is on my side of the firewall and is mine to do what I will with.

Comment: I don't know where you live, but note that it may not actually be 'yours to do what you will with'. If it's a party wall, then it's technically jointly owned by you and the person on the other side. Local regulations or HOA regulations may have restrictions on what you can do with them. That said, if it's truly 'your side' then my guess stands...you may have a masonry wall in the middle and the stud you are drilling into is merely a furring strip (rather than a full thickness stud)

Comment: FWIW, patching sheetrock isn't that hard. It might just be easiest to cut a small hole and peek in. If you make the hole behind where the TV will be placed, you won't even have to worry about patching it all that neatly.

Comment: There is a masonry wall, which is the party wall, but I am fairly sure this is not what I am drilling into, otherwise there would be no room for the power outlets behind the drywall.

Comment: Hmm...how deep are your outlet boxes?

Comment: Putting a hole in a firewall may be prohibited depending on how the wall is constructed (drywall can be the fire proofing). But since you say you have outlets in the wall, this probably isn't an issue for you. Since you're drilling a hole for the bolt, put another a few inches over to see what's there. I agree the most likely reason is masonry.

Comment: they are three inches

Comment: I don't see how it can masonry when one of the other studs on the same wall had no issues :(

Comment: Yea, I have no other guesses. Might have to crack the wall open. Keep us posted!

Comment: So I made a small hole in the wall... the stud is a 1x2. Never seen a 1x2 stud before!

Comment: I'd consider that more of a furring strip. Hard to say, but it may not be load bearing at all...merely there to hold up the sheetrock. That doesn't explain the outlet boxes...how are those 3" deep? I wonder if your masonry wall is uneven...perhaps there's a bump out of the masonry wall?

Comment: I suspect that they used shallow outlets for that particular wall, was basing that 2" number on my utility room.

Would it be safe to support a load with furring strips? They seemed pretty sturdy.

Comment: I'd be concerned that there is a steel plate covering electrical wires. I'd put a strong magnet up to the wall to see if it sticks, tap in the hole with something metal, etc. to find out.

Comment: Could also be something like a metal HVAC duct, water pipe, etc.

Comment: @NotCodingCoder the 2" furring strips are put up just to hold provide a surface they can screw the sheetrock into (as DA01 mentioned) unless this is a very small tv I would not recommend using the furring strips to hold up tv mount. Your other option would be you may be able to mount into the masonry but that would need to be checked with building code/fire inspector because I doubt that wall is included in your castle.

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer Has this mystery been sorted out?  If so, consider posting an answer, as it might help others in similar situations.

Comment: @Tester101 it's embarrassing... I was drilling into a concrete wall.... the time I was able to drill through I happened to go into mortar (which I repaired)