# Drill getting stuck about two inches into stud

Tags: drill, mounting, studs

I'm trying to mount my flat screen.  I found a stud using a stud finder and can definitely feel that I'm drilling into the stud but about 1.5-2 inches in, the bit gets stuck.  I proceeded with drilling in the screw but it gets stuck at the same spot.  I can get the screw in a little further with a wrench but still not far enough to hold the mount flush with the wall.  The screws are very long.  Any idea what might be happening?  There are three different spots on the stud where I have to drill these screws in (vertically) and it's happening with every one of them.

Thanks!

Comment: Does a drill bit get stuck, or do screws get stuck?  It isn't clear if you're drilling pilot holes or not.

Comment: Both the bit and the screw gets stuck.  I drilled pilot holes, the bit got stuck, I put in the screws and then they got stuck, as well.

Comment: I think Ecnerwal hit the nail on the head then - only other thing that I can think of is if you're really going into furring strips or the wall is "flat studded".  See [this post](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/31998/why-cant-i-drill-into-studs-more-than-1-1-2-inches?rq=1).

Comment: Yeah, either of those could absolutely be the case.  Not sure what my options are at this point but sounds like it's definitely time to break out the spackle on this area.

Answer (score 1):

**Hope** you haven't done any significant damage to whatever you are hitting, and choose a different stud  - or else open up the wall and look. At "1.5 to 2 inches" there's no requirement to put protective steel plates over things in the wall like wires and plumbing, so you have probably found something like that with your drill bit and very long screws.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I don't think I've actually gotten through anything - whatever is there is pretty solid.  I'll just have to take it down and try to figure out something else. Thanks again